# How to Enable Automatic Laravel Page Refresh with Vite in PhpStorm?

Tags: laravel, tailwind-css, phpstorm, vite

**UPDATE:** with the latest update PhpStorm to PhpStorm 2023.2.1 this bug is disappeared

I'm working on an `home.blade.php` page in Laravel with Vite and Tailwind CSS using PhpStorm, and I'm facing an issue where the page doesn't automatically refresh when I make changes. Unlike when I use Visual Studio Code, where real-time updates work seamlessly.

I've started Vite using `npm run dev`, and the page does refresh, but only after I manually click on it. Is there a way to configure PhpStorm or my development environment to achieve automatic real-time updates, so I can see changes without having to click on the browser window when using an external monitor?

I'm using Laravel 10, PhpStorm 2023.2 with new interface, MacBook Air M1, different versions of node.js (from 14 to 20)

This is my `vite.config.js`:

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: ['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'],
            refresh: [
                'resources/routes/**',
                'routes/**',
                'resources/views/**',
            ],
        }),
    ],
});
```

Comment: please check https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/vite/no-hot-reload-with-new-laravel-vitefor some hints

Answer (score 0):

I found that hot reloading works with the default Vite configuration, but you need to save the file manually with Cmd+S or wait for some idle time. There is also an option to automatically save files after a specified idle time, but it seems to work incorrectly. For instance, I have it set to 1 second, but I end up waiting for more than 10 seconds for the file to save automatically.

It seems that problem is in calculating the idle time in PhpStorm.